# Allowing access to protected area for multiple users from one organisation

Tags: access-control

I have a website which has a password protected area of content. This content can by accessed by a number of employees of a subscribing company.  For example, The Acme Widget Co. has 100 employees, each signing in with an individual company email address and password.

The Acme company have asked if there's a way of allowing their employees access to the protected area without logging in.  I am assuming that they wish to do this on fixed in-house and mobile devices.

The website is Linux/Apache/PHP/MySQL.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this please?  Or even if this is possible

Thank you

Comment: Is the problem the process of logging in, or is it the sharing of the single credentials?  If it is the latter, you could implement a registration process that allows registrations only for users that can verify that they have control of a email address at the company's domain.

Comment: @stephenOstermiller.  It seems that the company find that having users log in to the site a barrier to the site usage.  They feel that if the users did not have to log in then the take-up among the users would increase.   The problem therefore seems to be as you posted 'the process of logging in'..